# Repeatedly getting "ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file error". Not sure if it from Oracle or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library

Tags: .net, oracle, iis

We are getting "ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file error" when accessing a stored procedure using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library 18.6.0. Upgrading to 21.12.0 didn't help. The web application is deployed on IIS 10, .NET Framework 4.7.2 and Database version is 12c

The application works fine when no. of requests are low (1/2 requests per second). But as soon as no. of requests increases, we start getting this error.

The way we are accessing the stored procedure is as follows:

```
try
{
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        //Step 1 : Instantiate the command object
        var cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = spName;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        //Step 2 : Add parameters to the command and execute
        AttachParameters(cmd, paramArray);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

The procedure returns a VARCHAR2 type variable as Output paramater whose value is captured like this:

```
var returnedFromSP = (string)(OracleString)paramArray[17].Value;
```

where paramArray[17] is passed to the procedure like this:

```
paramArray[17] = new OracleParameter("OUTPUT_PARAMETER_OF_SP", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, returnedFromSP, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

I have searched in this forum and found a few related posts but could not find a definitive answer that works for us.

Comment: For that kind of issues, you need technical support from Oracle, https://support.oracle.com/portal/

Comment: Does this error only appear on iis? does the web application work properly locally?

Comment: Yes, this error only appears on IIS. Locally the applicaion runs well. The application runs well in IIS also, for a certain time. But as soon as no. of hits per second goes a little higher, the error starts to appear.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.